# how to create temperature heat map on a web?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api, heat-map

I'm work on a website of weather data .

I need to make heat map with temperature data to show the status of temperature in the state

my data(lat,lng,temp), I'm trying to work with Google maps but it embed only  (lat,lng) .

can any one know how to make it or know other applications can help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like [this](http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/example-heatmap-leaflet.html)? Then you might want to try [Leaflet](http://www.leafletjs.com) with [this](https://github.com/sunng87/heatcanvas) or [this](http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/example-heatmap-leaflet.html) heatmap plugin.